# Why does Backtrack 5 r3 connection errors in a VM?

Tags: backtrack

When ever i use backtrack metasploit it says rex:connection something .... etc

I am using backtrack inside vmware and use a NAT connection to the vmware....

I was wandering if there is a reason why whenever i use backtrack in vmware and try to connect to a wan ip that it gives me a connection error?